# How do I print a sequence of "1 2 3" for a length up to an input integer?

Tags: python

for instance:

```
input=7 -> print : 1 2 3 1 2 3 1
input=2 -> print : 1 2
```

I've only been able to print the whole "1 2 3" repeated for the input integer with the code below. (input=2 -> print : 1 2 3 1 2 3)

```py
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for num in range(1,4):
        print(num, end="")
        num += 1
```

Comment: How about
```n = int(input()); 
out = [1,2,3]*(1 + n//3); 
print(out[:n])
```

Comment: I dont think so, you can run the above snippet and check.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what  your code outputs and what you want instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to accomplish this:

```
for x in range(int(input("number:"))):
    print(x%3+1,end=' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible solutions. `itertools` provides `cycle` that cycles over desired values:

```
from itertools import cycle

c = cycle((range(1, 4)))

for k in range(7):
    print(next(c)) # prints 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1
```

The modulo trick is not difficult to understand, especially for those educated in programming. However, when writing Python I would prefer this more Pythonic solution. After all, the whole point of Python is to provide readable code and high level abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done with a generator using `yield_from`.

```py
def from_seq(seq):
    while True:
        yield from seq


gen = from_seq([1, 2, 3])
z = [next(gen) for _ in range(7)]
print(z)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: That's interesting - I thought `seq` would be exhausted and you would get `StopIteration`.

Comment: @JussiNurminen you would if not for the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access element in `[1, 2, 3]` based on index modulo 3.

```py
values = [1, 2, 3]
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    index = i % len(values)
    print(values[index], end=" ")
```

This is a good method if you want to repeat different values, e.g. if you want to have pattern `4 2 2 1 4 2 2` for input `7` just set

```py
values = [4, 2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write,

```
print(" ".join([str((i%3)+1)  for i in range(n)] ))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
n = int(input())
out = ""
seq = "123"
j=0
for i in range(n):
    if j<len(seq):
        out +=str(seq[j])
        j+=1
    else:
        j=0
        out +=str(seq[j])
        j+=1
print (out) # print: 12312
```

Answer (score -1):

A easy to understand answer:

```
n = int(input())

repeat_times = int(n / 3)
remainder = n % 3

store = []

if repeat_times > 0:
    for i in range(0, repeat_times):
        for j in range(1, 4):
            store.append(j)

if remainder > 0:
    for i in range(1, remainder + 1):
        store.append(i)

for i in store:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: Not a good solution as it some use the complexity On^2, the problem can be solve with O(n). Concatenate of loops are often a bad Idea, just when its needed.

Answer (score -2):

Simples way is to use modulo operation:

```
input = int(input("enter your number:"))
for i in range(input):
    print(i % 3+1, end=' ')
```

Comment: Seems the same as @XxJames07- below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71706512/2081835

Comment: it seem to be clear and with pep8 standars but yes, cntrl c + cntrl v